# How to do SSH with -i option and bypassing password entry

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, rsa

Using ssh, I want to access

```
Machine1 --> Machine2
```

Let's say Machine2 has IP address: 133.165.14.22.

I have copied `id_rsa.pub` from `Machine1` to `Machine2`
Then in `Machine2` I have already did this:

```
cd ~/.ssh
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

But when I tried to do SSH from `Machine1`

```
ssh -i /Users/neversaint/.ssh/id_rsa neversaint@133.165.14.22
```

It still asked for password.

```
neversaint@133.165.14.22's password:
```

How can I do it correctly, so that it won't ask for password?

Answer (score 2):

`ssh-copy-id` enter password the first time, that will put the right key in the right place.

if you don't have a key,  generate a new one `ssh-keygen`

Comment: delete your authorized key file,  and recopy.

Comment: Tried that too, still cannot

Comment: output of `ssh -vvv machine2` please

Answer (score 1):

Check the SSH daemon configuration file in Machine2 located at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and check the following fields exist:
`RSAAuthentication yes`
`PubkeyAuthentication yes`
`AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Also check and ensure the `authorized_keys` file is only readable/writable by you:
`chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Note: If you make any edits to the conf file, restart the SSH daemon:
`sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: In addition to this, ensure the private key (id_rsa) and the .ssh directory itself is not group or world writable.

Comment: try `ssh -vvv` and see if it says rejecting....

Comment: @JacobEvans: Here is the ssh -vvv results http://dpaste.com/00M4C8A.txt

Comment: you has no keys..... `ssh-keygen`

Comment: @JacobEvans: I don't get it. I already have `/Users/neversaint/.ssh/id_rsa` and `/Users/neversaint/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: @TLin where should I do ssh restart? Machine1 or Machine2? I tried at Machine2 it gave `ssh: unrecognized service`

Comment: not according to ssh... `debug1: identity file /Users/neversaint/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory`

Comment: @JacobEvans: Why is ssh -vvv cannot identify that?

Comment: You only need to restart the ssh daemon in Machine2 if you altered the configuration file.

Regarding the ssh verbose results, you forgot the -i when you ran ssh with verbose. Run it again: `ssh -vvv -i /Users/neversaint/.ssh/id_rsa neversaint@133.165.14.22` and update the results.